# Simplify exponents

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

Consider the following expression

```
Var = ( m^((a + b + c)/(3 n + j + d)) k^(a + b))^(f/(a + b));
```

Then, I take the ratio

```
    Var/m^(2/3)
```

and my output is

```
(k^(a + b) m^((a + b + c)/(d + j + 3 n)))^(f/(a + b))/m^(2/3)
```

Why Mathematica does not collect the exponents of $m$? It happens a lot of time and I would like to solve.

Which command should I use? Simplify and FullSimplify are not actually working.

Comment: You can use `PowerExpand`. This transformation is not valid for all possible values of the variables though. Check the examples in the documentation, and the use of the `Assumptions` option of this function.